# first occurrence of string after match perl

Tags: perl

I'm parsing a pcap file with perl. I have requests and responses. I would like to find all transactions that are not complete(requests not having responses). My Requests look like
ReqInfo, ReqData, ReqMsg and responses RespInfo, RespData, RespMsg. I have done basic count of Req and Resp. The no of requests is greater than response by 1. It is large file, cannot figure which request was missed. I have managed only

```
perl -lne 'END {print $c} map ++$c, /ReqInfo/g' file.pcap
```

The Requests and Responses are tied up by transactionID. I was planning to add transactionID to an array after each successful ReqInfo and delete transactionID from array after each RespInfo match. After entire search, I'm expecting the array to have list of all orphan transactionID. As it is pcap file, there are no rules with delimiters. I can have a bunch of Req in single line or each Req in separate line or fragmented data across multiple lines

Im looking for way to find 1st occurance of transactionID after ReqInfo. I can have a bunch of ReqInfo in single line or each ReqInfo in separate line or fragmented data across multiple lines

Comment: use a hash, not an array

Answer (score 1):

On finding a request,

```
++$c{$tran_id}
```

On finding a response,

```
--$c{$tran_id}
```

- Any transaction with the same number of requests and response will have a score of zero.
- Any transaction missing a response will end up with a positive score.
- Any transaction missing a request will end up with a negative score.